Integration of Mapbox key in blender for the 3D building
Can we import 3D buildings from Mapbox direct into blender or there is any other way to import buildings. I am not talking about OSM. I want to import mapbox buidlings

Hello, you seem to assume we know what mapbox is, could you elaborate a little bit on that ?
